# Python Mutilevel Import

Tags: python, module, relative-import

I'm having trouble if relative imports. The directory structure is:

```
folder
    app.py
    src_1
         __init__.py
        database
            db_declare.py
            __init__.py
        pages
            page_1.py
            df_prep.py
            __init__.py
```

Okay, now I have on:

```
#On app.py
from src_1.pages import page_1

#On page_1.py
from df_prep import df

#On df_prep.py
from database.db_declare import *
```

But I still get

```
"*\folder\src_1\pages\page_1.py", line 9, in <module>
    from df_prep import df

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'df_prep'
```

When I run `app.py`. I've tried adding ".." to `sys.path`, but it ends up adding to many "..". I tried to
Thank you. I wanted to keep the imports inside the scripts unchanged, meaning if two scripts are in the same folder there should be no reason to write `from pages.df_prep import df` inside `pages_1.py`.
I'm open to suggestions, but I really would not like to change too much about the file structure.

Answer (score 1):

`src_1` is a package. `folder` is not, so `app.py` is not in a package (but everything else is).

Relative imports in packages require `.`:

```py
# in page1.py
from .df_prep import df
```

```py
# in df_prep.py
from ..database.db_declare import *
```

See detailed answers here: [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your imports to:

```
#On app.py
from src_1.pages import page_1

#On page_1.py
from .df_prep import df

#On df_prep.py
from ..database.db_declare import *
```

Comment: When I run this inside app.py, it's alright, but when I do inside page_1.py I get ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: Yes, that's a different issue. It may be worth reading the link in @dwhswenson answer as this will better explain relative imports.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify complete path starting from src_1. This is because the code is executed from point of view of app.py.

```
#On page_1.py
from src_1.pages.df_prep import df
```